# How to carry over records to x amount of dates in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a Tableau project (my first).  I have a list of flight legs that include a count of consecutive overnights and the date the first overnight takes place.  I have a bar chart that shows all overnights, but it only counts the record once on the first date.  Logically, this is what I am looking to accomplish (if it were VBA, I know how I would solve it).

```
C = Nightly Count
D1 = 1st Nightly Date
D2 = D1 + C
Once D2 is known, apply a copy of the record to all dates in between D1+1 and D2.  Thereby increasing the overall count for each date.
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Is D2 a separate field in your table?  If so, I would approach this by looking to see if the D2 field is NULL, and if not, then using the DATEDIFF() function to count the number of days between D1 and D2.  The result then becomes your "C" value.

Comment: I ended up revamping the excel model that creates the data for the Tableau project and was able to get the results I needed.  Thanks